# Authenticated proxy for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, http-proxy

I'm behind an authenticated proxy, and I'm planning on installing Windows 8. I know that [one can set the proxy settings for the apps via `netsh winhttp`](https://superuser.com/questions/397577/how-to-setup-a-proxy-for-metro-ui-apps-in-windows-8-consumer-preview).

I remember that one cannot set authentication settings via `netsh` (atleast not on Windows 7, I doubt it has changed), so is there any other way to do this that works with authentication?

Comment: Is it for metro or desktop applications ?

Comment: I doubt it... http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/49b36903-747c-41ba-9b89-09893df81ba2

Comment: @TomWijsman: Not understood your doubt, but in your link the answer by Rugved Likhite using CCProxy seems useful for both types of applications. You might post it as an answer.

Comment: @harry It's for the metro apps.

Comment: @Manishearth: The answer found by TomWijsman converts an authenticating proxy into non-authenticating, so can solve your problem.

Comment: @Manishearth: It's not only for the Metro apps, the first step sets (or should set) a proxy in Internet Explorer which will be used by all application whom use the proxy settings from Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems I've scanned the link [I've found earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/469200/authenticated-proxy-for-windows-8/491056#comment583960_469200) a bit too fast and there is indeed an answer there:

> I am using Windows 8 Professional RTM behind my campus proxy. It's a squid proxy with basic authentication.

> 1. Install CC Proxy. This software created a local proxy server on my PC. I used my own IP address as my proxy server in LAN settings and this enabled me to access the internet without asking for proxy everytime as CCproxy used my campus proxy as the cascading proxy.

> 2. Type in the netsh command in prompt so that the apps start using the local proxy. (no authentication on local proxy due to CC Proxy)

> ```
>     netsh
>     winhttp
>     import proxy source=ie
> ```

> 3. Metro apps are programmed to prevent access of internet through a local proxy.
>    Download ['Loopback Exemption Utility'](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204091513/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx).

> This allows metro apps to access internet through your locally created proxy.
> Refer to [SKuzn's post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2aa72be-4964-459a-a220-5cf00ce187a9/windows-8-rtm-still-has-problems-with-quotmetroquot-apps-going-through-proxy-servers?forum=w8itpronetworking). Everytime you install a new metro app from the store, you need to exempt it for accessing internet through local proxy by using the Loopback Exemption Utility.

> 4. Also, set

> ```
>     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing
> ```

> to `0` and then go enable the following options in the Group Policy:

> 1. Open "Local Group Policy Editor" (`gpedit.msc`)
> 2. Navigate to "Computer Configuration - Administrative Templates - Network Isolation".
> 3. Enable "Proxy Definitions Are Authorative" and "Subnet definitions are authorative".

— **Source**: [MS Social Technet: proxy settings for metro apps](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49b36903-747c-41ba-9b89-09893df81ba2/proxy-settings-for-metro-apps?forum=W8ITProPreRel) (Modified, doesn't only apply to Metro)

Comment: I'd actually solved this by doing something similar-- I installed squid on a different machine on campus (always on) and used that as a proxy